# applying CSS for particular td tag in a column

Tags: html, css

In the following cshtml file, I want to apply CSS style to specific td tags where "want to add style here" is written. Is it possible to achieve it using class or do I have to use an id. The CSS works fine when it's written as inline. is there any mistake in writing the order of precedence of the tag in the CSS style sheet?

```css
.table-module2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.table-module2 .main-table th {
    line-height: 530px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.table-module2 table tbody tr .sp-name1 {
    text-align: initial;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.table-module2 table tbody tr .sp-name2  {
    text-align: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-module2" v-if="details.length > 0">
<table class="main-table">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>NO</th>
                            <th>name1</th>
                            <th>name2</th>
                            @foreach (var names in Model.TableName)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    <table class="table-heading">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> <div class="vertical"> @names.TableName </div> </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> <div class="vertical2"> @names.TableName2  </div> </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            }

                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        @foreach (var item in Model.name)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>


                                <td class="sp-name1">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Key)</td> <! --want to add style here--> 
                                @foreach (var names in Model.name)
                                {

                                    if (item.Key == names.Key)
                                    {
                                        <td class="sp-name2">@Html.DisplayFor(model => names.Value)</td><! --want to add style here--> 
                                    }
                                }


                                @foreach (var names in Model.name)
                                {

                                    if (item.Value.Contains(names.TableName))
                                    {
                                        <td>●</td>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <td></td>
                                    }
                                }

                            </tr>
                        }

                    </tbody>
                </table>
               }
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something a little more obvious like changing text color or targeting all TDs to ensure you CSS is actually working on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use `class`!

When in look into your code in chrome developer tools and look at the `elements`. I get this:[image] so I edited your `CSS` to match that and now you could access and style your `sp-name1` & `sn-name2`.

(**NOTE**: I also added `color: red;` to show that the CSS works.)

```css
.table-module2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.table-module2 .main-table th {
    line-height: 530px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table.main-table tbody tr td.sp-name2 {
    text-align: initial;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
table.main-table tbody tr td.sp-name2  {
color: red;
    text-align: initial;
}
```

```html
<table class="main-table">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>NO</th>
                            <th>name1</th>
                            <th>name2</th>
                            @foreach (var names in Model.TableName)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    <table class="table-heading">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> <div class="vertical"> @names.TableName </div> </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> <div class="vertical2"> @names.TableName2  </div> </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            }

                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        @foreach (var item in Model.name)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>


                                <td class="sp-name1">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Key)</td> <! --want to add style here--> 
                                @foreach (var names in Model.name)
                                {

                                    if (item.Key == names.Key)
                                    {
                                        <td class="sp-name2">@Html.DisplayFor(model => names.Value)</td><! --want to add style here--> 
                                    }
                                }


                                @foreach (var names in Model.name)
                                {

                                    if (item.Value.Contains(names.TableName))
                                    {
                                        <td>●</td>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <td></td>
                                    }
                                }

                            </tr>
                        }

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir,  "td.sp-name" this is what I have been missing.